# How to create a dynamic progress bar with JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created some quizzes and I want to create a dynamic progress bar so when you click 'complete' at the end of each quiz it adds 20% to the progress bar. So when all 5 quizzes are done it reaches 100%. However, I am unsure of how to do this in jQuery or js this is my code so far. I have 5 js files with the same format just different questions in the array, I am just linked one below.

HTML

```
        <div class="container">
              <div id="question-container" class="hide">
                <div id="question">Question</div>
                <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                  <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
                  <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
                  <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
                  <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="controls">
                <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
                <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
                <a href="home.html"><button id="complete-btn" class="complete-btn btn hide">Complete</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const completeButton = document.getElementById('complete-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    completeButton.innerText = 'Complete'
    completeButton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}
var totalQuizes = 5;

    // run this either on page load, or dynamically when you have a new percentage to update
    $(function(){
        $("#NumberComplete #percent").css( {"width": (numberComplete / totalQuizes) * 100 + "%" } );
});

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What does HTML stand for?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language', correct: true },
      { text: 'Hyper Text Markup Language', correct: false },
      { text: 'Home Tool Markup Language', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which character is used to indicate an end tag?',
    answers: [
      { text: '<', correct: false },
      { text: '*', correct: false },
      { text: '/', correct: true },
      { text: ';', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is making the Web standards?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Google', correct: false },
      { text: 'Mozilla', correct: false },
      { text: 'Microsoft', correct: false },
      { text: 'The World Wide Web Consortium', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the correct HTML for making a text input field?',
    answers: [
      { text: '<input type="textfield">', correct: false },
      { text: '<input type="text">', correct: true },
      { text: '<textfield>', correct: false },
      { text: '<textinput type="text">', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Choose the correct HTML element for the largest heading:',
    answers: [
      { text: '<head>', correct: false },
      { text: '<h6>', correct: false },
      { text: '<heading>', correct: false },
      { text: '<h1>', correct: true }
    ]
  }
]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mostly use css with a little bit of Jquery. Create a full width div with a div inside to represent your progress bar, such as this

```
<div class="progress-bar-container" style="100%">
    <div id="my-progress-bar" class="progress-bar" style="width:0%;height:20px"></div>
</div>
```

then with Jquery you can set the width of the progress-bar to the percent that you want.

```
$('#my-progress-bar').css('width', '20%')
```

Then style it however you want, add background color to red or to make it more flashy you can add some transitions to animate it